# Overwrite f.input label with only f.label showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have the following piece of code :

```
<div class = "span 3">
<%= f.label :volunteers, "Number of Volunteers" %>
<%= f.input :volunteers %>
</div>
```

And this is what is showing on the web page :

Number of Volunteers
volunteers [#input box is here  ]

I want to remove the "volunteers" label, as it's being automatically inserted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Try this:

   `<div class = "span 3">
     <%= f.input :volunteers, :label => "Number of Volunteers"  %>
   </div>`
2. Start using the `simple_form` gem.  It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: will be even easier then, just step 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<div class = "span 3">
  <%= f.label :volunteer, "Number of Volunteers" %>
  <%= f.input :volunteers %>
</div>
```

You don't have a phones label? Are you missing code?